# Save local state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

In my App I use several `Container` components. In each `Container`, there are `Buttons`.

Depending on the `state` of the App, the `Buttons` are clickable (or not). Whether a `Button` is disabled or not, is managed in the local `state` of **each** `Container`. 
The results and state of the App can be saved and loaded.

And here comes the problem:
When I save (or load) the App, its rather hard to "*extract*" the `state` of the `Buttons` from **each** `Container`. Saving in the global `state (Redux)`is rather easy.

But how can I save the local `state` from **each** `Container` **and** how can I feed it back to each `Container`?

Reading the local `state` is managed through a parent `Component` which calls methods from a child `Component`. I am aware that this is an antipattern, but it works.

```
export class SomeConmponent {
....

    onClickSaveProjecthandler(event) {
        const localStateProjectSettings = this.childProjectSettings.getLocalState();
        const localStateLayerFilter = this.childLayerFilter.getLocalState();

        return {
          "ProjectSettings": localStateProjectSettings,
          "Filter": localFilter
        };
      }


    render() {
        return(
            <ProjectSettingsContainer onRef={ref => (this.childProjectSettings = ref)}/>
        )
    }
}
```

Any better suggestions?

Comment: You already mentioned redux; why not use that instead of local state?

Comment: »I am aware that this is an antipattern, but it works.« It clearly doesn't, seeing how you are facing this problem.

Comment: @IngoBürk I dont want to use `redux` because greying out buttons or not is something which *should* be done in the `component`/`container`. No need to re-render the whole site only for greying out a button (which will happen when I use `redux`!)

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned, using redux to have a single point of truth is a great ideia. And to "feed" the state back to containers, you have to map state and props to your components.

This is a container example brought from the oficial doc:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { setVisibilityFilter } from '../actions'
import Link from '../components/Link'

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    active: ownProps.filter === state.visibilityFilter
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onClick: () => {
      dispatch(setVisibilityFilter(ownProps.filter))
    }
  }
}

const FilterLink = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Link)

export default FilterLink
```

The connect does all the magic.

Comment: I dont want to use `redux` because greying out buttons or not is something which *should* be done in the `component`/`container`. No need to re-render the whole site only for greying out a button (which will happen when I use `redux`!)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use Redux and you somehow miscomprehended its architecture as being synonymous with *global* state only. One of the reasons Redux was made was to address the issue of saving states of multiple independent components.

However, here's an entirely different take on the answer: why not use a global **state serializer** and connect each component to it? If you don't like the idea of referring to a global variable, a better alternative would be to create some sort of dependency injection (DI) framework that works with React. I've created a library a while back, called [AntidoteJS](https://github.com/TypeForce/AntidoteJS), that does exactly this. You don't need to use it, but it shows how you how it can be done. Just take a look at [the source](https://github.com/TypeForce/AntidoteJS/blob/master/packages/react-antidote/src/index.tsx).

Here is something quick and dirty. I haven't tested it, but it shows the basic idea:

```
import { inject } from "antidotejs"

export class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  @inject("StateSerializer")
  serializer

  constuctor(props, children) {
    super(props, children);
    this.serializer.load(props.id);
  }

  setState(newState) {
    super.setState(newState);
    this.serializer.save(newState);
  }

}
```

Comment: I dont want to use `redux` because greying out buttons or not is something which *should* be done in the `component`/`container`. No need to re-render the whole site only for greying out a button (which will happen when I use `redux`!)